# Immutable value in Swift 2

Tags: swift, watchkit, xcode7-beta6

I have a project in which this code does not give me problems, but in Xcode 7.0 beta 6 it skips the warning and I can't find a way to fix it

```
 func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void) {
    print("Mensaje recibido:\(message)")

    if let msg = message as? String{ //Error here
        // do something with the uname
    }

    replyHandler(["reply" : "OK"])
}
```

Comment: What warning is it skipping?

Comment: Why are you trying to cast the message dictionary [String : AnyObject] into a String? Are you trying to get a value out of the dictionary and cast the AnyObject to a String?

Comment: The warning message says inmmutable value
if let msg = message["Status"] as? String{ //Error msg replace for _
                
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mr Beardsley said, the instruction `if let msg = message as? String` won't work because you're trying to cast `message`, which is a dictionary, to a String optional.
This should do the job:

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void) {
print("Mensaje recibido:\(message)")

if let msg = message["/* Whatever key you want to select */"] as? String {
    // do something with the uname
}

replyHandler(["reply" : "OK"])
```

}

Replace the 'Whatever key you want to select' part with the key paired to the value you want to assign to msg.

Comment: Sorry, the code of the question I forgot to put the key, but in my code if I really start yet still fails
if let msg = message["Status"] as? String{ 
      //Error msg replace for _
 }

Comment: If the error you're receiving tells you to replace `msg` with `_` that's almost certainly because you're not using the `msg` constant inside the if-let statement braces. Try writing `println(msg)` inside those braces as a test, and see if the error disappears.